# How to programmatically set a value to a node attribute

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a node named let's say "group" to which I added a field called "foo".

How would I programmatically give a value to this "foo" attribute?

I would like to do this when a user is joining a group. This joining process does not involve a saving of the current node, it just add data to a custom table i made. So Hooks don't apply here.

I am guessing i would have to:

1-load the node
2- add data to my attribute
3- resave the node

I am still trying to figure out how to do that, so if anyone has experience to share that'd be much appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without more information... but does Rules do you want want?

Comment: Did you read comments added below ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually very straight forward, here is how i have done it:

```
$group = node_load ( $nid );
$group-> foo = 'bar';
node_save ($group);
```

That's it.

Hope that' ll help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of different hooks you can use to edit the node with. See [Node API Hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/group/node_api_hooks/) for more information on those.

I would personally use [hook_node_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) to add a value to "foo" this will then be added to the node before it's saved to the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Digital, although using hook would mean that i am already in a node editing process. What i would like to achieve is a snipet of code that would load a node in the background, add a value to one of it s attribute and then save it .

Comment: It that case you'll need to use the hooks for loading the node and then saving it. All this would need to be packaged into a custom module.

Comment: Thanks for the input, though the process doesn't involve any hooks at all. Just simple node load and node save, see below